# Selenium No Element Exception error for getting text off web page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue with trying to receive the text value of one of my IWebDriver elements. I have used Find Element By XPath, however I keep getting this "no element exception" error. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

Console.WriteLine("Which car brand would you like to search?");
string car = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Which model?");
string model = Console.ReadLine();
model = model.Replace(" ", "-");

Console.WriteLine("What year?");
string year = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Which trim?");
string trim = Console.ReadLine();
trim = trim.Replace(" ", "-");


IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
string url = string.Format("https://www.kbb.ca/{0}/{1}/{2}", car, model, year);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);


IWebElement closeModal = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ZipCodeDisclaimer\"]/a"));
closeModal.Click();

IWebElement trimLink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href*='/" + trim + "/']"));
trimLink.Click();

IWebElement modalClose = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ZipCodeDisclaimer\"]/a"));
modalClose.Click();

IWebElement tradeInClick = driver.FindElement(By.Id("aPrivateSell"));
tradeInClick.Click();

IWebElement odomCheck = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TextBoxKM"));
IWebElement tradeValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"RightRectangle\"]/text/tspan[2]"));
Console.WriteLine(tradeValue.Text);


Console.ReadLine();
```

The error is coming from:

```
IWebElement tradeValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"RightRectangle\"]/text/tspan[2]"));
```

and i will attach the screenshot of the error message

I have tried using Wait Until, but have had no luck with that. Maybe I am doing something wrong... please help!

Comment: Where is your try with wait?

Comment: You are getting some inputs from the user, edit your post and hard code those values,  because I don't get it - what is trim?.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons :

Do this element is constant or the `xpath` value can change dynamically ?
Additionally the value you wrote in `xpath` should be unique.

```
("//*[@id=\"RightRectangle\"]/text/tspan[2]")
```

If other element in page will have this exact value `(RightRectangle)` then it will have issue of missing your expected element.
Anyway, I more recommend using find element by `Id` and not by `xpath` since runtime will be more quicly. Goodluck !